# why am I getting a load error for mandrill-api gem on aws?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sinatra, mandrill

I am using Sinatra and ruby on AWS, I have tried with both 2.1 and 1.9.3 using the AWS cli to create my elasticbeanstalk application.

I have installed the mandrill-api gem on my local machine and ruin bundle install (although that may not be necessary) and included it in the Gemfile gem `'mandrill-api'` and in the app.rb file `require`'mandrill-api'`
but I keep getting the "Load error" cannot load mandrill-api.

Has anybody encountered and resolved this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `require 'mandrill'`, not `mandrill-api`. See [the docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.ruby.html)